# Diffraction grating (finding number of emission lines)

Tags: visible-light, waves, diffraction

I came across a question on isaacphysics.org where youre given information about a diffraction grating, the spacing of the gaps and the colour and location (in degrees) of 8 different maxima, of four colours.
The question asks how many emission lines are evident from the information given.

[image: Prompt text]
[image: Question text]

My issue is that rather than not understanding the context I just have no idea what the question is asking and what it means by emission lines. Im familiar with diffraction gratings but I've never came across a question like this...

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! unfortunately your link doesn't lead to the required question as far as I can tell :/

Comment: Oh no sorry thats the wrong link 
This should be the correct one https://isaacphysics.org/questions/grating_spectrum?board=0d73b930-0bd9-42ef-8ccb-2692c2e8dc19

Comment: Can you copy the question, rather than making us click a link that could go bad.

Comment: Not specifically copy it but i added pictures in place of the link if that helps

Answer (score 0):

If they are calling the angles listed on the chart emission lines then I see eight all together. Starting with violet at an angle of 32.7 followed by 35.5, 33.1, 35.2, 42.4, 46.6 and 35.4. 
After reviewing I'm wondering now if it has more to do with the way the eight points blend together. 46.6 and 46.7 combine to make one line, 35.2, 35.4 and 35.5 combine to make one line and the other three lines are 32.7, 33.1 and 42.4.

Comment: I would have assumed this, i mean there being 8 values and all but the correct answer is 5...

Comment: Like I said the last one seems out of place. Are you counting the first five or something else? Thanks

Comment: Im really not sure why its five
I only found out the answer by putting in values until it said correct. What im unsure of is if they mean the same thing by maxima of intensity and emission line

Comment: I am curious what their description of emission lines is.

Comment: Me too thats what threw me off
Have you come across the phrase before in questions like this?

Comment: OK I may be wrong but I'm having fun studying this. I am wondering if it is the way the eight points blend together. For instance the 46.6 and the 46.7 combined to make a blue green emission line. .35.2, 35.4  and 35.5 also combine to make an emission line. The other three lines would be at 32.7, 33.1 and 42.4 for a total of five